# Finding the constants of an exponential equation

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Find $A$ and $k$ if $f(x)=Axe^{-kx}$ has a critical point at $x=10$, and at that critical point, $f(x)=12$.

I'm entirely lost in this question. I can find the general derivative of $Axe^{-kx}$ pretty easily, but solving gets difficult fast. I'd at least like a hint first to see what direction to even move in.
([The problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IfvKM.png))

Comment: Do you know what critical point is?

Comment: And what did you get when you took the derivative?  How do you use that to find critical points?

Answer (score 0):

$$f'(x)=Ae^{-k x} (1- k x)$$
we know that $f(x)$ has a critical point at $x=10$ thus
$$f'(10)=0\to Ae^{-10k}(1-10k)=0$$
which means $$1-10k=0\to k=\frac{1}{10}$$
Furthermore we know that $f(10)=12$ so
$$f(x)=A x e^{-k x}\to f(10)=10Ae^{-\frac{10}{10}}=12$$
and finally
$$k=\frac{1}{10};\;A=\frac{6}{5}e$$